# writing into a div using php

Tags: php, html, authentication

This always shows nothing as $msg does not get echoed and when I used sessions to solve the problem it always took 2 wrong tries to tell me that what i entered is wrong. So I tried this and it still did not work. I want to know the proper way of writing into a div using php; I cut down parts of the code which I believe have nothing to do with the problem. If there are any other mistakes I made please point it out.

```
<?php 

if (!isset($msg)) $msg = "";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    if ($_POST['formname'] == "Signup Form")
        SignUp();
    else if ($_POST['formname'] == "Signin Form")
        SignIn();

function SignIn()
{
    include 'CONNECT_DB.php';
    $pass = md5();

    $SQLSTATEMENT = ;
    $AMOUNT = mysqli_query($con, $SQLSTATEMENT);
    if ($DATA = mysqli_fetch_array($AMOUNT))
    {
        if($DATA['ACTIVE'] == 1)
        {
            session_destroy();
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['USER_State'] = true;
            $_SESSION['USER_ID'] = $DATA['USER_ID'];
            $_SESSION['time'] = time();
            header('Location: index.php');
        }
        else
        {
            if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
            $_SESSION['USER_ID']=$DATA['USER_ID'];
            $_SESSION['time'] = time();
            header ("Location: Reactivate.php");
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        $msg = "your email is not submitted or your password is invalid";
    }
}

/// ... some validation 

echo "<form name='Signin Form' method='POST' action='" . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . "'>
          <input type='hidden' name='formname' value='Signin Form'>
              <table cellspacing='0'>
                  <tr>
                      <td width='25%'></td>
                      <td>
                          <table width='100%'>
                              <tr>
                                  <td><p class='formP'>Email:</p></td>
                                  <td><input class='inputBarLogIn' type='text' name='Email' autofocus>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                  <td><p class='formP'>Password:</p></td>
                                  <td><input class='inputBarLogIn' type='password' name='Password' autofocus>
                                      <div class='divAttention' id='PasswordLogInDiv'>
                                      </div>";
echo $msg;
?>
```

Comment: Why do you `echo` so much?

Comment: i tried alot of stuff but still $msg does not show so i tried puttin it all in the same php tags

Answer (score 1):

The following would probably work better and be easier to edit in future.

```
[...]
/// ... some validation 
?>

<form name='Signin Form' method='POST' action='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='formname' value='Signin Form'>
<table cellspacing='0'>
    <tr>
        <td width='25%'></td>
        <td>
            <table width='100%'>
            <tr>
                <td><p class='formP'>Email:</p></td>
                                    <td><input class='inputBarLogIn' type='text' name='Email' autofocus></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p class='formP'>Password:</p></td>
                                    <td><input class='inputBarLogIn' type='password' name='Password' autofocus> 
                                        <div class='divAttention' id='PasswordLogInDiv' ><?php echo $msg; ?></div>
                                    </td>
```

You can jump between HMTL and PHP like so:

```
<?php
    if( something == something ) {
?>
        <p>Something is something</p>
<?php
    } else {
?>
        <p>Something is not something</p>
<?php
    }
?>
```

This may make it easier to write you page if you separate the PHP logic from the HMTL and saves you having to echo it all out.

Comment: well i didn't know of this so thanks for the info but still why donesn't msg show up ?

Comment: its because, it doesnt come to else part always. define $msg="test" at the initial assignment and see. you should get it echoed.

Comment: You can check the page source to see if the message is being written out but not displayed due to formatting. However it may be that your code doesn't enter that else block where `$msg` is set as @mazraara said.

Comment: Also I've just edited my answer to include some missing `</td>` (cell closing) tags from your example. It appears that some of these where left out after the `<input>` tags.

Comment: that's not the case o echoed smth in the else scope and it got echoed normally